# Filtering the name (string) of a new device just created

Tags: string, bash, grep

I think this is a *greping* problem rather than a networking one:

My computer uses to have **multiple `ppp` connections** running at the same time, sometimes 0, sometimes 1, 2... etc.

For example, **before** connecting:

```
$ ifconfig | grep "ppp"
ppp0      Link encap:Point-to-Point Protocol
ppp1      Link encap:Point-to-Point Protocol
```

And, **after connecting** a new one:

```
$ ifconfig | grep "ppp"
ppp0      Link encap:Point-to-Point Protocol
ppp1      Link encap:Point-to-Point Protocol
ppp2      Link encap:Point-to-Point Protocol
```

How could I programmatically guess the `ppp` device (`ppp2` in this example) **just created**?

EDIT-1: This could be another possible **before** connecting case:

```
$ ifconfig | grep "ppp"
$
```

(No `ppp` devices active)

EDIT-2: This could be another possible **before** connecting case:

```
$ ifconfig | grep "ppp"
ppp0      Link encap:Point-to-Point Protocol
ppp2      Link encap:Point-to-Point Protocol
```

A "hole" at `ppp1`: it does not exist, so the new `ppp` status **after** connecting will be:

```
$ ifconfig | grep "ppp"
ppp0      Link encap:Point-to-Point Protocol
ppp1      Link encap:Point-to-Point Protocol
ppp2      Link encap:Point-to-Point Protocol
```

I think the `ppp` devices behave that way.

Comment: `ifconfig | awk '/ppp/{x=$1}END{print x}'` may work

Comment: did you want to print the last `ppp` line?

Comment: Can there be more than one created or nothing created also?

Comment: @JID , is your proposal supposed to extract the *new* `pppN` device, or just the *last* (numerical) one? I presume sometimes it could exist `ppp0` and `ppp2` before connecting, so the new one would be `ppp1`.

Comment: @AvinashRaj , not the entire line, please. I just want to obtain `ppp2` (in the example).

Comment: @anubhava , indeed, there could be any number of `ppp` devices already created (no devices or 5, for example, and even "holes", like `ppp0` and `ppp2` but not `ppp1`). Well... I don't think there will be something like `ppp57` , but it could be a good idea to deal with the possibility.

Comment: It would retrieve the last occurrence of it from ifconfig. You may want to add that comment to the question as it was unclear this could be the case.

Comment: @SopalajodeArrierez: So I guess this approach should work. Run `ifconfig | grep "ppp"` before-connect and store the output in a temp file. Then run same command again after-connect and **get a diff** to extract newly added `ppp` devices.

Comment: Or peruse /var/log/messages (or wherever your particular distro stores the messages) to find the most recent one set up. Or run `ps -ef | grep pppd` and find the most recent one (but I'm not entirely sure how to tie a PID of a pppd process to the interface it's running on...).